# Which phase of request processing does the ngx_http_proxy_module register itself?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-module

I am developing a custom module and I need to use the `proxy_pass` directive. Therefore I want to specifically determine which phase of request processing is the directive called?

Comment: `proxy_pass` is a content handler declaration (you can have only one content handler per location) which is being called at the CONTENT phase (obviously).

Comment: @IvanShatsky how is it so obvious that it is CONTENT phase?

Comment: Because it is a definition of the **content handler** (like the `fastcgi_pass`, `uwsgi_pass`, etc.)